# C reading from a live file ( file keep growing in size )

Tags: c, fread, live-streaming

I have an application that is recording live , the capture file keep growing in size 
using fread() and feof() , but feof() is breaking the loop early , so what's the best technique to keep reading from the stream

- should I wait and then I can advance the file stream ?
- should I open the file again and advance to position by calculating the total of read     bytes?
- maybe something else ?

the code will have to read the file , build a packet and send it 
packaging and sending is going well with fixed size files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would monitor the file (something like `select(2)`). When notified, I would `read` as much as possible then wait again.

Comment: well at the receiving side , do you know any simple video playback program written in C so I can implement select there too ?