# Reading a growing file

Tags: c, linux, file-handling

If I encounter `feof()` and then `stat` shows that the file has grown, is there a way to read the added data without doing a `fclose()` and `fopen()`?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757304/how-to-read-a-growing-text-file-in-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864769/c-reading-from-a-live-file-file-keep-growing-in-size).

Comment: Thanks @Tsukuyo, but the first link is C++ which uses a different set of file i/o calls, and the second says to use `select()` which doesn't seem viable (as far as I understand `select()` at any rate).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can call `clearerr` on the file, or perform any seek opereration such as `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR)`.

Comment: `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR)` clears the `eof` flag?  That's news to me (and quite helpful!).

Comment: C99 7.19.9.2 The fseek function, paragraph 5: "After determining the new position, a successful call to the fseek function undoes any effects of the ungetc function on the stream, clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream, and then establishes the new position."